# ¿como extraer data de una lista eficientemente en RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un hash con toda la información de un modelo y quiero traer una fila especifica, tengo un procedimiento que estoy mas que seguro que no es el más eficiente.

```
ropas = Ropa.all
_id = 4
tomalo = {}
puts "======================"
puts "_id: #{_id}"
ropas.each do |r|
  puts r.inspect
  if r.id == _id
    tomalo = r
  end
end
puts "======================"
puts tomalo.inspect
puts "======================"
```

Y esta es la salida:

```
======================
_id: 4
  Ropa Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "ropas".* FROM "ropas"
  ? app/controllers/ropas_controller.rb:38
#<Ropa id: 1, nombre: "pantalon"
#<Ropa id: 2, nombre: "camisa"
#<Ropa id: 3, nombre: "medias"
#<Ropa id: 4, nombre: "short"
#<Ropa id: 5, nombre: "zapatos"
#<Ropa id: 6, nombre: "corbata"
#<Ropa id: 7, nombre: "franela"
#<Ropa id: 8, nombre: "falda"
======================
#<Ropa id: 4, nombre: "short"
======================
```

¿Cómo puedo extraer la data mas eficientemente?

Comment: ¿has considerado usar  [`.find_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)? quizás sea todo lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `#find` para buscar por `id`:

```
Ropa.find(4)
#<Ropa id: 4, nombre: "short"...>
```

Si no estás trabajando directamente con el modelo, `find` también te sirve, pero utilizándolo con un bloque:

```
ropas.find { |ropa| ropa.id == 4 }
#<Ropa id: 4, nombre: "short"...>
```

Comment: Tienes razón amigo Gerry, es la respuesta mas obvia, pero no es tan fácil , el problema lo tengo yo que no supe explicar completamente la pregunta y puse una información que puede generar ruido, si bien el ejemplo lo genero a partir de un modelo, realmente esa lista se genera sin un modelo en específico, se genera de varios modelos, el punto es que quiero extraer una fila completa de una lista que me entregan, donde hay un id, pero no tiene nada que ver con un id de ningún modelo, es solo un número secuencial que se genera al crear cada fila de esa lista compuesta. ¿me supe explicar mejor?

Comment: @rrg1459 Creo que sí te entendí; mira la actualización en la respuesta.